# Is an absent batsman out?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

One of the opposition batsmen failed to turn up. Is he out?

This matters especially for my competition where teams receive 0.25 points for each wicket taken.

Comment: While Nij's answer is almost certainly correct in terms of the laws of the game, you really need to be asking this question to your league organisers. It doesn't really matter if somebody on the Internet says you're right if the organisers say "no".

Answer (score 2):

Law 1.2 requires that the players of each team be provided in writing to the umpires before the toss, and thereafter not changed without the agreement of the opposing captain.

Law 40 requires that the next batsman be ready on the field within three (3) minutes of a dismissal, unless Time is called. If the three minutes elapse without the batsman being ready, they are liable to be out, Timed out on appeal by the fielding team.